# Assert that Callback passed to mock function is called

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

The following setState hook is passed to the ageVerificationService which is then called
on a click event. My issue is this service has been mocked in my unit test so I am unable to
assert that setState hook has been called.

How can I mock my service so it calls any passed functions?

```
  // SetState Hook
  ageVerified && setIsVerified(true);

  // AgeVeri Service
  ageVerificationService(dispatch, () => setIsVerified(!isVerified));
```

UNIT TEST

```
// Mocking setState hook
const setState = jest.fn();
const useStateMock: any = (initState: any) => [false, setState];
    (useState as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(useStateMock);

// Mocking the service
jest.mock('../../../services/ageverification', () => jest.fn());

expect(ageVerificationService).toBeCalledWith(
  mockDispatch,
  expect.any(Function)
);

expect(setState).toHaveBeCalled(); // Failing as not called by mocked service
```

Comment: *"this service has been mocked in my unit test so I am unable to assert that setState hook has been called"* - you can't assert it because it *isn't happening*, it's not the responsibility of the component what the service does with the callback. Also I wouldn't mock useState, you should generally not mock what you don't own - write a test double for the service that invokes its second parameter, then test that the component reflects the updated state through its public API (DOM, props, interactions with collaborators).

Comment: Mocking useState is A common practice

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, and that still wouldn't make it a *good* one.

Comment: so how are you going to achieve full coverage if your component relies on value set by setState hook?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think that would be any impediment to getting good test coverage. A component's internal state is an *implementation detail*, your tests should not be interacting with it directly (one of the *benefits* of a function-based component from a testing perspective is that it prevents you tinkering with the state prop). Again, test through the *public API* - think about how the changing the value of `isVerified` impacts what's displayed in the DOM or passed to collaborators, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ageVerificationService as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(
      (dispatch: Dispatch, callback: Function) => {
        callback();
      }
    );
```

I simply added a mock implementation to the AgeVerification service